# Does NiFi Site-to-Site support IPv6?

Tags: apache-nifi

Can a Remote Process Group be configured to point at another NiFi instance using the http://[ip:v6:add:ress:here]:8080/nifi syntax?

**Update**

On a Mac, when I try to access http://[::1] I get the default webserver "It works!" message.  When I try to access http://[::1]:8080/nifi, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` ... so clearly NiFi (Jetty?) is receiving the request, but just not honoring it.

Is there a setting to change this behavior?  It's a little odd that the protocol wouldn't be supported *just because* (...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd love to have a more experienced / knowledge person comment on the technical ramifications of this, but I found that IPv6 access can be enabled.

**How to**

In the `nifi/conf/bootstrap.conf` file, change ...

`java.arg.4=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

... to ...

`java.arg.4=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false`

And obviously restart (if NiFi is currently running).